# How can i show just "total36" in this case?

Tags: text-processing

For my Homework I tried in linux to just get the output `total 36` from the output of `ls -s` as produced here:

```shellsession
vboxuser@Ubuntu:~$ ls -s
insgesamt 36
4 Bilder  4 Dokumente  4 Downloads  4 Musik  4 Öffentlich  4 Schreibtisch  4 snap  4 Videos  4 Vorlagen
```

I tried some commands with `awk` or `du` but it didn't give me the output I wanted and the nearest I could come with was

```shell
ls -s --block-size=1024
```

Is there a command which can help me?

Comment: Hey, welcome here. Can you please just copy and paste the text from your terminal, and use the "code formatting" button, labeled `{}` in your question editor, to add it to your question? Thanks! Also, what is your homework problem statement? Is it "please get this string from this command's output" or is it "count the files in the directory"?

Comment: Kindly always state the commands you already tried. This is important information.

Comment: Read `man head`

Comment: "The Question is please get this string from this command's output." but the command's output does not contain that string at all! Do you maybe need to change the language in which the command outputs strings?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
ls -s | grep ^total
```

In the list of files, each file has its size before its name, so even if there's a file named "total" it will not get grepped.

Note that you must change the shell language (locale) from German to English for this to work!

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**:

```
~$ ls -s | perl -ne '$. == 1 && print $_;'
```

OR:

```
~$ ls -s | perl -ne 'print $_ if $. == 1;'
```

---

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6):

```
~$ ls -s | raku -ne '++$ == 1 && .put;'
```

OR:

```
~$ ls -s | raku -ne '.put if ++$ == 1;'
```

Since `ln -s` prints the total on the first output line, the answers above basically address the question, *"How do I print the first line of <STDIN> ?"*

Both languages (Perl and Raku) implement and rely on the `-ne` "non-autoprinting linewise" command line flags, allowing the line-number variable to control output.

Using Perl, the `$.` line number variable is tested to equal 1; then the `&&` short-circuiting operator `print`s the `$_` topic variable. Alternatively (second example), an `if` conditional is used.

Using Raku, an anonymous `$` scalar is pre-incremented (`++$`) and tested to equal 1; then the `&&` short-circuiting operator `put`s the `$_` topic variable. The code `.put` is short for `$_.put`, which is equivalent to `put $_`. Alternatively (second example), an `if` conditional is used.

Sample Output (all four code examples):

`total 36`

https://perldoc.perl.org
https://docs.raku.org

Answer (score 0):

When `ls` is called with any one of the `-s`, `-l`, `-n`, `-o`, `-g` options to list the contents of a directory like when called without file name argument in which case it defaults to listing `.` (the current working directory), it prefixes its output with:

```
total <a-number>
```

With the number being the sum of the number of allocated 512-byte units of disk space occupied by the files being listed. With the GNU implementation of `find`, it's in 1024 byte units instead unless called with a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in its environment or the block size is specified with a `--block-size` option or a `BLOCK_SIZE` or `LS_BLOCK_SIZE` environment variable.

With busybox or toybox (Android) `ls`, you get 1024 byte units even when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment and there doesn't seem to be any way to fix that non-compliance.

Most other implementations should report a number of 512-byte units.

With `ls` implementations that have been localised, that `total` may be translated into the language of the user which seems to be your case here. To get `total` regardless of the user's locale, you can invoke it with `LC_ALL=C` in its environment, the C aka POSIX locale being the only one where you're guaranteed to have `total` as that's how it's specified by the standard.

So:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 LC_ALL=C ls -s | head -n 1
```

To get the total number of 512-byte units except with busybox/toybox.

For number of 1024-byte units, with GNU `ls` specifically:

```
LC_ALL=C ls --block-size=1024 -s | head -n 1
```